# Une "mare de pleurer"... (mare de pleurs) ?

Tags: expressions

Je lis dans différents extraits numériques d'Ernest Pépin, *Coulée d'Or*, la phrase suivante :

> — Comment elle est ta maman ? Quelle est sa couleur ? Comment
>   s'appelle-t-elle ? Où habites-tu ? De temps en temps, je lâchais un
>   maigre morceau de réponse dans une **mare de pleurer**. Je m'étais trompé
>   de jupe. Ma mère réapparut sous les regards plus ou moins réprobateurs
>   des badauds.

Le contexte est le suivant : un petit garçon guadeloupéen a perdu sa mère dans la foule et se met à pleurer.
Les deux extraits que je possède contiennent cette formule étrange que je remplacerais volontiers par **"mare de pleurs"**. L'un des documents en ma possession précise que l'extrait correspond à la page 113 de l'édition Gallimard.

Quelqu'un pourrait-il vérifier le texte d'origine ? Ou bien est-ce que **"une mare de pleurer"** est une expression dont je ne connaissais pas l'existence ? Merci d'avance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce texte d'Ernest Pépin contient bien *mare de pleurer* dans sa version originale.

Ernest Pépin est un auteur Guadeloupéen, qui bien qu'écrivant en français standard, parsème ses écrits de français guadeloupéen et expressions locales. Mais dans le cas de *mare de pleurer*, et bien que je n'ai pas de dictionnaire de français guadeloupéen sous la main, je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse de français guadeloupéen mais probablement d'une création langagière en partie propre à l'auteur. Ernest Pépin est connu pour ses créations langagières sous forme de néologismes, mais il emploie ici un procédé qui se retrouve fréquemment en français antillais (détournement du sens d'un mot par changement de classe grammaticale).

Dans ce même passage de son autobiographie *Coulée d'Or* on trouve ces autres créations lexicales :

> Je la suivais, agrippé à sa jupe, remorqué par ses pas.[...] Soudain une bousculade nous **dessouda**.

> **Je pris courir** et ayant repéré une jupe rouge **je me ressoudai** à elle.

<sup>(C'est moi qui souligne)</sup>

Voici un [article](https://cedille.webs.ull.es/10/23zanoaga.pdf) paru dans la revue [Çédille](https://cedille.webs.ull.es/index10.htm) (revue espagnole de français) *Créations néologiques dans les romans d’Ernest Pépin, auteur antillais* dans lequel on retrouvera un aperçu de ces créations savoureuses propres à Ernest Pépin.

Donc oui, il faut comprendre « mare de larmes » / « mare de pleurs ».

[Voici un passage](https://www.assistancescolaire.com/eleve/3e/francais/travailler-sur-des-sujets-de-brevet/texte-d-ernest-pepin-serie-college-sept-2005-3_frde19) un peu plus complet d'où est tiré le paragraphe cité dans la question.

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse très complète.

Answer (score 2):

une mare de larmes serait plus approprié, même si "une mare de pleurs" est aussi correct (pleurs = larmes) mais cela pourrait porter à confusion avec "j'en ai marre de pleurer" ( I'm fed up to cry)

Dans "Alice au pays des merveilles" de Lewis Carroll, le chapitre III est "la mare aux larmes" . mare = pond, marre = fed up